# How to echo specific column names using "SELECT *" query, get_result() - MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch, associative-array

I have the following code:

```
public static function selectBy(Database $database, $columnName, $value){
    $connection = $database->getConnection();

    $stmt = $connection->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM `Logs`
    WHERE ' . $columnName . ' = ?;');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $finalResult[] = $row;
    }
    return $finalResult;
```

And it's implementation:

```
$logsArray = Log::selectBy($this->database, "ID", "423");
    foreach($logsArray as $key=>$logArray){
        foreach($logArray as $anotherKey=>$log){
            echo $log . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

I am trying to find a way to target only specific row fields that we're returned from the database, for example, echo only the IP of the first log that was returned.
another example is to assign all the fields that we're return to a Log object, one field to a variable at a time, or all at once.
The result will be a row of objects, of type "Log" that reflect what's in the database.

One more problem I have encountered is that I have an extra field in each row of the two dimensional array returned by fetch_assoc(), which is called "array + an incrementing number", for example:
Array 0
Array 1
Array 2
Clearly it's the array number inside the first array, using foreach it goes over it by default.
Any way to ignore it using foreach? Or remove / avoid inserting them in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: as of your question, you need to learn PHP arrays: `foreach($logsArray as $logArray) echo $logArray['ID'];`

Comment: This function isn't available for end-users, but for inside developers. The input to this function doesn't, or shouldn't at least, come from a user.